# OutOfMemoryError - from detect UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, detect

This class should check `currentFile` and detect encoding. If result is UTF-8 `return true`.

Output after runnig is - `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

For read data you need have **JDK 7** for this `Files.readAllBytes(path)`

**Code:**

```
class EncodingsCheck implements Checker {

    @Override
    public boolean check(File currentFile) {
        return isUTF8(currentFile);
    }

    public static boolean isUTF8(File file) {
        // validate input
        if (null == file) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("input file can't be null");
        }
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "input file refers to a directory");
        }

        // read input file
        byte[] buffer;
        try {
            buffer = readUTFHeaderBytes(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Can't read input file, error = " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (0 == (buffer[0] & 0x80)) {
            return true; // ASCII subset character, fast path
        } else if (0xF0 == (buffer[0] & 0xF8)) { // start of 4-byte sequence
            if (buffer[3] >= buffer.length) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((0x80 == (buffer[1] & 0xC0)) && (0x80 == (buffer[2] & 0xC0))
                    && (0x80 == (buffer[3] & 0xC0)))
                return true;
        } else if (0xE0 == (buffer[0] & 0xF0)) { // start of 3-byte sequence
            if (buffer[2] >= buffer.length) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((0x80 == (buffer[1] & 0xC0)) && (0x80 == (buffer[2] & 0xC0))) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (0xC0 == (buffer[0] & 0xE0)) { // start of 2-byte sequence
            if (buffer[1] >= buffer.length) {
                return false;
            }
            if (0x80 == (buffer[1] & 0xC0)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static byte[] readUTFHeaderBytes(File input) throws IOException {
        // read data
        Path path = Paths.get(input.getAbsolutePath());
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        return data;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

- How do solve this problem?
- How do do check for UTF-16 on this way
  (need we worry abou this or this is only useless troubles)?

Comment: If you only need the first four bytes of the file to detect the heading, why are you reading the entire file into memory?  Think about what happens if this is, say, a 1GB file.

Comment: @mellamokb How do circumvent this of the resource costly process?

Comment: @nazar_art Search for "Java read file tutorial". Find one that talks about `InputStream`s.

Comment: Can you say something about realize detect UTF-16 in this example?

Comment: "If you only need the first four bytes of the file to detect the heading, why are you reading the entire file into memory? Think about what happens if this is, say, a 1GB file." - so, search for a tutorial that uses `InputStream`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to read the entire file.

```
private static byte[] readUTFHeaderBytes(File input) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(input);
    try{
        byte firstBytes[] = new byte[4];
        int count = fileInputStream.read(firstBytes);
        if(count < 4){
            throw new IOException("Empty file");
        }
        return firstBytes;
    } finally {
        fileInputStream.close();
    }
}
```

For detecting other UTF encodings use given patterns:

```
Bytes           Encoding Form
00 00 FE FF     UTF-32, big-endian
FF FE 00 00     UTF-32, little-endian
FE FF           UTF-16, big-endian
FF FE           UTF-16, little-endian
EF BB BF        UTF-8
```

Comment: The method described here is based on the UTF BOM (Byte Order Mark). Some applications generate this header, but some don't. So this method will work for some files but it's not completely versatile. What `file` and similar apps sometimes do is to read in a sample, e.g. the first 64 kB of a file and run the whole decoding process on it. It's more versatile than just checking for BOM but uses less resources than loading and decoding the whole file.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski agree, there is no 100% way to know encoding

Comment: Apache IO Commons provides an easy way to detect file encoding if a BOM is present : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html

Comment: @Smertokogt How do change this part `if (0 == (buffer[0] & 0x80)) { ... return false;  }` from UTF-8 to UTF-16 detection encoding? How do decide this number `(... & 0xF8)` and after `0xF0 ==`?